# How to find Python 2 interpreter path from Python 3 script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I have a file called `a_python2_script.py` with content

```
print "Hello"
```

and call it in Python 3 with:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(["python2", "a_python2_script.py"])
```

This works, but I do not want to hardcode `python2` interpreter call, since the program should run on Windows and Linux.

I know about `sys.executable` but that would give me the path of the current (i.e. Python 3) interpreter. What is the pythonic way to get the Python 2 interpreter path from within the Python 3 script?

Note: I am calling an external Python 2 library and have no chance to convert it to Python 3.

Comment: Can't you just write your whole program in Python 2? "but then people who have only Python 3 won't be able to run it" isn't a valid objection, because that's true of your current approach too.

Comment: It's not that I am just getting started. The Python 3 source code base is quite big. This is a requirement that came up later. I can not port the whole code to Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.get_exec_path()` (available from 3.2) to get a list of directories that will be searched for an executable.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: paths = os.get_exec_path()

In [5]: for p in paths:
   ...:     for prog in ["python2", "python2.exe"]:
   ...:         attempt = os.path.join(p, prog)
   ...:         if os.path.isfile(attempt):
   ...:             print(attempt)
   ...:             
/usr/local/bin/python2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be one possible way to figure it out. I am currently running Windows and have Python installed using Anaconda and Anaconda3. My `PATH` contains both of these folders.

A simple script could check each `PATH` location for the presence of the Python executable. You could then execute `python --version` at each location:

```
import sys, os
from subprocess import Popen

python_paths = []

for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
    for executable in ["python", "python.exe", "python2"]:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, executable)):
            python_paths.append(path)

for path in python_paths:
    Popen([os.path.join(path, "python"), "--version"])      

print(python_paths)
```

On my Windows machine this gives:

```
['d:\\Anaconda', 'd:\\Anaconda3']
Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (32-bit)
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (32-bit)
```

Tested using Python 3.4.3. I am not currently able to check the outcome for Linux though.